# Open several SQL Scripts on Toad starup

Tags: oracle, toad

i am using Toad for Oracle V11.

And i'm already using **View>Toad Options> File to execute on new connections** to set some parameters when i start a new connection.

Here is also the option **File to load on startup**, but here i can only select a single file to open on startup. But I always need three different scripts when I open Toad and i don't want to merge them to one file.
Is it somehow possible to always open those three different scripts when i open toad?

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, as far as I can tell.

See whether creating a **project** (using the Project Manager; it's the 6th icon in my TOAD 14 toolbar) helps, as you can add folders or folder **items** (that would be your scripts) to it.